printing a diamond, even and odd lines
while (True):
        print("enter the number of rows you'd like\t")
        n = input_number()
        if n < 3:
            print("please input a number greater than or equal to 3")
        elif n >=3:
            n = n//2 + 1
            temp = n
            #top of diamond
            for m in range(1, n + 1):
                for q in range(n, 0, -1):
                    print(" ", end = "")
                n = n-1
                for q in range(1, m + 1):
                    print("* ", end="")
                print("")
            #bottom of diamond
            n = temp - 1
            for m in range(0, n):
                print("  ", end="")
                for q in range(1,m+ 1):
                    print(" ", end="")
                for q in range(n, 0, -1):
                    print("* ", end="")
                n = n-1
                print("")
            while True:
                print("Would you like to play again? y/n" )
                question = input_string()
                if question == "y":
                    print("Restarting...")
                    break
                elif question == "n":
                    print("Exiting...")

                    return
                else:
                    print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
                    continue

when i input an even number of rows, i always get odd. for example 4 rows prints out 5 rows
i was expecting 4 rows to be printed not 5. its always odd, how can i make a change that isn't too complicated that will fix it?

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

What would a diamond with an even number of rows look like?

Your variables should mean the same thing throughout your code. Your n variable is pulling at least triple duty and represents the total number of rows, the number of rows in the top pyramid, or the number of rows in the bottom pyramid. This overloading makes your code hard to read and debug. Creating separate variables with meaningful names (not just m, n, etc.) should help you a lot in debugging your own code.

For a diamond with even rows, there's a clear top and bottom half, but for odd rows, there's an ambiguous middle. Consider using modular division by 2 with n % 2 to separate even/odd cases.

see my answer on this post for a neat way to create a diamond, which you can tweak slightly to work with your user inputs & needs.
